# Laravel not displaying images in storage folder while using artisan server

Tags: php, laravel

The image is stored in 'storage/app/public/gallery'

I have already used  `php artisan storage:link` command.

The images are being displayed when I run the app in apache. 
But not in artisan or my ipage server

http://vazz.edottechno.com/storage/gallery/33.jpg

Comment: did u u use route in laravel?

Comment: for the images? I don't think so. How do I do it?

Comment: This probably means the file is not at the specified location. Are you perhaps on Windows?

Comment: Yes I'm using windows

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to give www-data the permission to read files in storage/ path. 
If not, check if you are using a dynamic url (url helper). In this case, that might be because the env_url is not properly set.